# How do I strtok through a str and assign each token to an array that is a global variable

Tags: arrays, c, char, global-variables

In this code, I call the input function and assign the input to a global variable. then i parse the global string using `strtok()` in my **parseFunction** separating it out by the spaces. I assign each token to a global array.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];

void getInput() {
      printf("input command ");
      fgets(input, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
}

void parseFunction() {
      int i = 0;
      char* tok;
      char* delim = " \n";
      while(tok != NULL) {
            parsed[i] = tok;
            i++;
            tok = strktok(NULL, delim);
      }
      parsed[i] = NULL;
}

int main() {

      getInput();
      parseFunction();

}
```

I am getting the following errors and I cannot understand what is going wrong.

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’
         parsed[i] = tok;
                   ^
shell.c:51:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘void *’
     parsed[i] = NULL;
```

Comment: `char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];` -> `char *parsed[50];`. Because you are only trying to store a pointer to the string and not a copy of the string.

Comment: thank you!!  I thought it might be the way I was declaring it

Comment: Side note, I believe you are missing the initial `strtok()` call, `tok = strtok(input, delim);`

Comment: `parsed[i]` has type `char [50]`, which is an array type.  It is not a valid LHS, and you cannot assign to it.  You can only assign to *elements* of it.

Comment: lizard, with `char* tok; ... while(tok != NULL) {`  the first time `while(tok != NULL)` is executed, what value do you think `tok` has in the compare?

Answer (score 1):

The comments are helpful in terms of getting you through compilation, but there are a few more gotchas waiting for you. I'm guessing that BUFFERSIZE is the max length of a string and that you wanted an array of 50 strings that are of size BUFFERSIZE. What you specified was BUFFERSIZE strings of size 50. I think you want -

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char parsed[50][BUFFERSIZE]; /* size of each of 50 strings is the same as input now, which I think is what you wanted */
```

If you agree with Kaylem's comment about storing pointers (which will work), then it actually should be.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char *parsed[50]; /* an array of 50 pointers to char */
```

But you may or may not want to rethink that. The next problem is how you're iterating through the input string with strtok. `tok` is uninitialized when you first test its value entering the while loop. The result is undefined. Any wild thing could happen there from memory access crash to simply being NULL by accident and never entering your loop. I think what you want is.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char *parsed[50];

void parseFunction() {
      int i = 0;
      char* tok;
      char* delim = " \n";
      for (tok = strtok(input, delim); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, delim) { /* you have to use input the first time you call strtok */
            parsed[i++] = tok; /* short-cut */
            /* maybe a check on i to make sure it doesn't go beyond 49 or you'll crash */
      }
      parsed[i] = NULL;
}
```

That's if you really want to store pointers to places inside the `input` string. But let's say you reuse the string `input` for another round of input and add the tokens to the end of `parsed`. If you put the above in a loop and got more data from the console, using `input` again, and intended that to be added to "parsed" like it was one big set of tokens. Someone types in 10 tokens and you store the pointers to the tokens - pointers to the inside of `input` which `strtok` is modifying by replacing delimeters with null terminators. Then you get another 5 and you add those 5 pointers to the end of your "parsed" array. The first 10 would now be pointing to garbage, because `fgets` would have overwritten the contents of input, which `strtok` had set up to be read as a collection of substrings. The behavior would be undefined again, but almost certain to produce garbage. The safer way to do this is to actually copy the strings. You use the first of the two declarations above and do something like -

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char parsed[50][BUFFERSIZE];

void parseFunction() {
      int i = 0;
      char* tok;
      char* delim = " \n";
      for (tok = strtok(input, delim); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, delim) {
            strcpy(parsed[i++], tok); /* actually move the chars into one of the strings in "input" */
      }
      parsed[i][0] = '\0'; /* use an empty string in stead of a NULL pointer */
}
```

Now, regardless of what happens to `input`, the contents of `parsed` is safe. Some picky C99 or C++ compilers will require you to cast `parsed[i]` as a `char*` for `strcpy`, as in `(char*)parsed[i]`. Technically, `parsed[i]` is of type `char (*)[BUFFERSIZE]`, but older C didn't care.

Answer (score -1):

In your code compiler complains,

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];

void getInput() {
      printf("input command ");
      fgets(input, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
}

void parseFunction() {
      int i = 0;
      char* tok;
      char* delim = " \n";
      while(tok != NULL) {
            parsed[i] = tok;   // here is error...
            i++;
            tok = strktok(NULL, delim); // this is strtok(original), if you didn't made a wrapper or your own...
      }
      parsed[i] = NULL; //here is error..
}

int main() {

      getInput();
      parseFunction();

}
```

A possible solution could be...

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
char input[BUFFERSIZE];
char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];

void getInput() {
      printf("input command ");
      fgets(input, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
}

void parseFunction() {
      int i = 0, j =0; //edit
      char* tok =NULL; //edit
      char* delim = " \n";
      tok = strktok(NULL, delim);  //edit...
      while(tok != NULL) {
            parsed[i][j] = tok;   //edit
            i++;
            tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
      }
      parsed[i][j] = NULL;  //edit
}

int main() {

      getInput();
      parseFunction();

}
```

Comment: *What you are trying to do is ,

`char **a`;*  ***NO!!!***  `char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];` is not a `char **`.  `char parsed[BUFFERSIZE][50];` is `BUFFERSIZE` array of multiple `char` arrays, each of 50 bytes.  There are no pointers involved with `parsed`.  `parsed[i][j] = tok;` is trying to cram the pointer `tok` into the `char` value at `parsed[i][j]`, with significant loss of information.  Turn on all your compiler warnings

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for correcting me and giving more clearity.. can I use that in my answer..